# how do I test web embedded fonts on my webpage?

Tags: css, embed, webfonts

I am working on a website that needs embedded fonts.

Everything looks great, except, if I delete the local Prelo fonts from my machine (backed them up) the fonts stop working in the browser. Of COURSE this is because there is an error in my code and I fix it and it works again.

(so the problem is... is there a work-around for "disabling" the local fonts or telling the browser not to look locally for fonts other than needed system fonts?)

Is there a way other than deleting the fonts locally to test in the browser? It seems that Chrome and FF default to my system fonts if they can't find the embedded fonts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Just rename the font you want to test, make sure its not a name you have locally.

i.e:

change:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: System;
     font-style:  normal;
    src: url(system.eot);
}

div {
    font-family: System;
}
```

to

```
@font-face {
    font-family: WebTest;
    font-style:  normal;
    src: url(system.eot);
}

div {
    font-family: WebTest;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this might happen by accident if you use FontSquirls webfont generator. It made "Fira Sans" into "fira_sans". Ugly, but not known by my system  : )

Answer (score 1):

Type Wonder will let you type in a URL and select a web font.  Then it will show you what your page would look like with the new font.  Pretty slick.

http://typewonder.com